# Change payment capture dropdown order in Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, php

I would like to change the order of the Capture Payment dropdown, it is located on the create invoice page in admin html when you chose a payment that allows capturing.

The order of the list is:

- Capture Online
- Capture Offline
- Don't Capture

I would like the Don't capture option to be on top.
Does anybody have an idea what file I should rewrite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to overwrite the template.

Create `local.xml` in `design/adminhtml/default/default/layout` folder and add this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout>
  <adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_new>
    <reference name="order_items">
       <action method="setTemplate">
          <template>sales/order/invoice/create/items_new.phtml</template>
       </action>
    </reference>
  </adminhtml_sales_order_invoice_new>
</layout>
```

Now create another file in `design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/invoice/create/items_new.phtml`.

copy all the content from `design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/invoice/create/items.phtml` to your file and then find following:

```
         <select name="invoice[capture_case]">
                  <option value="online"><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Capture Online') ?></option>
                  <option value="offline"><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Capture Offline') ?></option>
                  <option value="not_capture"><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Not Capture') ?></option>
              </select>
```

and replace that with:

```
          <select name="invoice[capture_case]">
                  <option value="not_capture"><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Not Capture') ?></option>
                  <option value="online"><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Capture Online') ?></option>
                  <option value="offline"><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Capture Offline') ?></option>
              </select>
```

This should work. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

That dropdown is hardcoded in an adminhtml template so it doesn't use a source model. What you can do is to overwrite the template `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/invoice/create/items.phtml`, more precisely this part:

```
              <select name="invoice[capture_case]">
                  <option value="online"><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Capture Online') ?></option>
                  <option value="offline"><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Capture Offline') ?></option>
                  <option value="not_capture"><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Not Capture') ?></option>
              </select>
```